# XML ! Help to solve bug between DTM & ACL files, with Arbortext Editor

Tags: xml, acl

To create our xml documents I’m using Arbortext Editor.

What is the bug to solve ?

When I create new entities, I have to declare it in the .acl file (edqm_ent_E_W7.acl).  We have to declare it in the .dtm file (dbgenentEN.dtm) too.
Sometimes, colleagues forget to declare these new entities in the .dtm file (dbgenentEN.dtm).
It generate the bug I need to solve, when we run the script in Arbortext Editor (this script runs in fact edqm_ent_E_W7.acl. It marks up our xml file).

The bug is :
I run the routine in Arbortext Editor.  Ifthe  acl file doesn’t find the entity in dtm file, Arbortext Editor deletes the text instead of keeping it (through ‘’break’’ command) or replace it by the specified text (in the example here : if ($Error>0) {ie PhEur}).
With this command, if there is an error, it should mark up with ‘’ ie PhEur ‘’.
Why our xml editor delete the text?

To understand better what the bug is, watch the video capture : https://youtu.be/aM4mP6S4ol0

To download the files : http://dl.free.fr/iXsltlaRB

Answer (score 0):

Yes our Arbortext is very customized for our company.

But we have this issue we can't solve... I don't know how to fix this bug when we forget to add the entity in DTM file...

*HansBigalke* is deleted by the command ''delete_mark'', but why this one *if ($Error>0) {ie PhEur})* is not working ?

I'm speaking with PTC here... but they don't answer me...https://www.ptcusercommunity.com/message/443919#443919